# Building Ardour 5

Tags: 17.10, music, ardour

I am trying to build ardour 5 on Ubuntu 17.10. When I try to configure it, it displays `pkg -config => No` How  do I get `pkg -config` to work. I have searched all over but no answers because its not a common problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I built Ardour. You will need all the prerequisites (explained later). Python 2.6 should already be on your PC. Build it with:

```
    ./waf configure
    ./waf
    ./waf install
```

It will ask for some dependencies, so install those 1 by 1. LIST:
`sudo apt install libboost-all-dev gcc g++ pkg-config libasound2-dev libgtk2.0-dev glibmm-2.4-dev libsndfile1-dev libcurl4-nss-dev libarchive-dev liblo-dev libtag1-dev vamp-plugin-sdk librubberband-dev libfftw3-dev libaubio-dev libxml2-dev libjack-dev liblrdf-dev libsamplerate-dev lv2-dev libserd-dev libsord-dev libsratom-dev liblilv-dev libgtkmm-2.4-dev` (ONE LINE)

Comment: It is working now..  Thanks. <3

Comment: I get this error still `Checking for 'pangomm-1.4' >= 1.4                    : not found 
The configuration failed`

Comment: I had to change liblrdf-dev to liblrdf0-dev to make it work, other than that it worked great (at least with the `waf configure`, trying to build now...).  Btw, I'm using the latest Ubuntu (bionic beaver) and Ardour's latest code from their git repo, as of today.

Comment: @cyniphile use `sudo apt install libpangomm-1.4-dev`

Answer (score 6):

**Update**: Building **Ardour 6** on **Ubuntu 20.04**

By trial and error, this might include some not needed packages:

This is from the previous answer, but with packages that errored removed:

```bsh
sudo apt install -y libboost-all-dev gcc g++ pkg-config libasound2-dev libgtk2.0-dev  libsndfile1-dev libcurl4-nss-dev libarchive-dev liblo-dev libtag1-dev vamp-plugin-sdk librubberband-dev libfftw3-dev libaubio-dev libxml2-dev lv2-dev libserd-dev libsord-dev libsratom-dev liblilv-dev libgtkmm-2.4-dev
```

And this is all the packages installed in my terminal history (there might be some overlap):

```
sudo apt-get install -y \
libglibmm-2.4-dev libsndfile1-dev libarchive-dev liblo-dev libtag1-dev \
librubberband-dev libfftw3-dev libaubio-dev libxml2-dev liblrdf0-dev \
libusb-1.0-0-dev libcunit1-dev libwebsocketpp-dev \
libpangomm-1.4-dev libsamplerate0-dev lv2-dev libcunit1-dev libcppunit-dev \
libudev-dev libserd-0-0 libcwiid-dev libxwiimote-dev libserd-0-0 \
libserd-dev libwebsocketpp-dev libwebsockets-dev libsord-dev libsratom-0-0 \
libsratom-0-0 libsratom-dev liblilv-dev liblrdf0 liblrdf0-dev
```

Then do the normal:

```
./waf configure
./waf
./waf install
```

Comment: am also on ubuntu 20.04. very helpful. Thanks!

Comment: this saved me so much time. thank you!!!